# Моделирование МП 8086

Tags: c, ассемблер, c++

Мне нужно сделать цикл выборки-исполнения команд. Описать как таблицу переходов. Все это на С или С++.

Можете привести небольшой пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таблица переходов - это стандартная вещь. В сети много материала по теме.

- [Конечные автоматы в C++](http://www.devexp.ru/2011/02/konechnye-avtomaty-v-c/)
- [Программная реализация нисходящего автомата с магазинной памятью](http://www.softcraft.ru/translat/lect/t07-07.shtml)
- [Кодогенерация времени компиляции Compiler-time code generation](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/alg/Static_Finite_State_Machine.xml)